# Quitar $ de precio para realizar operación

Tags: javascript, html

tengo este código js

```
var regularConverted = pricetoNum($regularPrice.text());
var bestConverted = pricetoNum($bestPrice.text());
//var discountAmount = (1-(bestConverted/regularConverted))*100;
var discountAmount = parseFloat(bestConverted)/parseFloat(regularConverted);
```

lo que pasa es que por consola me regularConverted y bestConverted me traen los valores bien, pero los traen con el signo $, entonces por ello no me hace la operacion, entonces la pregunta es como se lo quito?

Comment: Con que valores te llega regularConverted y bestConverted en la consola, y cual e sel codigo de la función pricetoNum

Comment: Dios mio que cabeza la mía los valores me llegan así $34.400, debe ser por el "$" que no me hace la operación, entonces la pregunta seria, como hago la operación hay? como quito el "$",

Comment: ¿Qué valores tiene `$regularPrice`? ¿Tiene por ejemplo '34400'?

Comment: $regularPrice llega por consola asi "$34.400"

Comment: si queres saber como sacar el $ de los valores te aconsejo que edites la pregunta, podes darle click aca [edit]

Comment: Depende de donde es que obtengas el $, ejemplo si lo obtienes en regularConverted puedes hacer: var regularConverted = pricetoNum($regularPrice.text()).toString().replace('$',''); y si te llega en $regularPrice.text() puedes hacer lo siguiente var regularConverted = pricetoNum($regularPrice.text().replace('$', ''));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te aconsejaria usar una funcion regular : `/^\D+/` esto te permite tomar unicamente los numeros de la cadena, aca te dejo 2 ejemplos.

este echo con jQuery y aplicando la exprecion simplemente en la string

```js
//jQuery 
var valor1 = parseFloat($("#valor1").val().replace( /^\D+/g, ''));
console.log(valor1);
var valor2 = parseFloat($("#valor2").val().replace( /^\D+/g, ''));
console.log(valor2);
var calculo = valor1+valor2;
console.log(calculo)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="$40.10" id="valor1">
<input type="text" value="$30.40" id="valor2">
```

este echo con Javascript en forma de funcion, (se puede usar tambien con jQuery)

```js
var valor1 = document.getElementById("valor1").value;
var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
var calculo = tomarFloat(valor1) + tomarFloat(valor2);

console.log(tomarFloat(valor1));
console.log(tomarFloat(valor2));
console.log(calculo);

function tomarFloat(texto) {
  return parseFloat(texto.replace(/^\D+/g, ''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="$40.10" id="valor1">
<input type="text" value="$30.40" id="valor2">
```

espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la metodo [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice)

**ejemplo:**

```js
// por si utilizas o no jquery
var $ = (s) => document.querySelectorAll(s);
// selecionamos el texto del elemento b que sea hijo directo p
let precio = $("p > b")[0].textContent;
// cambiamos a float "opcional"
// toFixed(2) es para obtener 2 decimales
result = parseFloat(precio.slice(1)).toFixed(2);
console.log(result);
$("p > b")[1].textContent = precio.slice(1);
```

```html
<p>precio: <b>$99.50</b></p>
<p>precio sin simbolo: <b></b></p>
```